# Federating learning process with poisson subsampling of participants

Tags: tensorflow-federated

I'm performing few experiments with `TFF`. In this one, I would like to sample the participating clients at each training around according to `poisson subsampling` where each client is sampled with a probability of `p = users_per_round / num_users`

At each round, `poisson subsampling` is performed until the list `sampled_ids` is filled with *unique ids* equal to the number of `users_per_round`.

```py
total_rounds = 100
num_users = 500
users_per_round = 150
lambda_value = np.random.rand()

for round_num in range(total_rounds):

   sampled_ids = []

   while len(sampled_ids) < users_per_round:

      subsampling = np.random.poisson(lambda_value, num_users)
      whether = subsampling > 1 - users_per_round / num_users
      for i in np.arange(num_users):
          if whether[i] and len(sampled_ids) < users_per_round and i 
             not in sampled_ids:
                  sampled_ids.append(i)


  sampled_clients = [train_data.client_ids[i] for i in sampled_ids]

  sampled_train_data = 
     [train_data.create_tf_dataset_for_client(client) for client in 
         sampled_clients]

  server_state, train_metrics = iterative_process.next(server_state, 
                                                 sampled_train_data)
```

Is there a better way of performing `poisson subsampling`, especially if the subsampling is applied in `differentially private FL`, so that the `RDP accountant` yields accurate privacy analysis results ?

What would be the best strategy to set the value of `lambda` other than `random` values ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Poisson subsampling means each user is included with probability `q`. The number of users in each round you get from this process is approximately Poisson distributed if `q` is small. If you want sample such that *on expectation* you have `users_per_round` users in a round you could do the following:

```
users_this_round = np.random.poisson(users_per_round)
sampled_ids = np.random.choice(num_users, size=users_this_round, replace=False)
```

If you want to choose exactly `users_per_round` users (which is technically not Poisson subsampling) you could do this:

```
sampled_ids = np.random.choice(num_users, size=users_per_round, replace=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that was really helpful.

In case the number of ```users_this_round ``` was much less than the expected```users_per_round```, is it safe to perform additional Poisson sampling rounds to collect the missing clients ? or would that violate the ```Poisson subsampling``` ?

Comment: Correct, that would violate Poisson subsampling.

Comment: Also I realized that to be really correct, the number of users per round should be sampled from a binomial distribution, not Poisson: `users_this_round = np.random.binomial(num_users, users_per_round / num_users)`.